# Pass an Array in as Arguments to Function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have the following function:

```
String.prototype.format = function() {
    var args = arguments;

    return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) {
        return typeof args[number] != 'undefined' ? args[number] : match;
    });
};
```

Now say I have the following code defined:

```
var dataItem = { membershipId: 1, userId: 3 };
var dataKeyNames = 'membershipId,userId';
var url = '/Admin/User?MembershipId={0}&UserId={1}';
```

What I'd like to do is call the format function passing in each value from the data item (for each data key name). For example if there was only one data key name then I would be able to say:

```
var formattedUrl = url.format(dataItem[dataKeyNames]);
```

But I need to be able to do a split on the dataKeyNames and pass each corresponding value from the data item in as arguments in the format function.

I'd appreciate it if someone could show me how this is done. Thanks

Comment: `dataKeyNames.split(',')`?  Then loop over the array and call `.format()` with the key's value?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I'm guessing they want it in "one" line. Where I'd guess using `.map()` on the split string, mixed with getting the respective values from the object, would give them the array they need to `.apply` to the function call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take this one step at a time.

First, you can split the string of keys into an array, using `dataKeyNames.split(",")`.

Then, you can call `map` on the array of strings to generate a new array - specifically, the values that you want to pass to your `format` method. This is where you interact with the `dataItem` variable.

Finally, you can use `url.format.apply` to actually **call** your `format` method with the new array. Note that it's possibly most important to pass `url` as the first argument to `apply` - that sets the `this` value that `format` will use.

Here's the code I came up with:

```
var formattedUrl = url.format.apply(url, dataKeyNames.split(",").map(function (val, index, array) {
    return dataItem[val];
}));
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/T4tHx/

To make it more readable, you can definitely split this up into several lines.

---

**References:**

- `String.prototype.split` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split
- `Array.prototype.map` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
- `Array.prototype.map` browser support - http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.map
- `Function.prototype.apply` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This worked a treat and is hardly any code.

Comment: @nfplee No problem! Just be away of the browser support for `map`: http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.map - but the MDN page provides a polyfill in those few browsers that don't support it